# How to script SQL object (tables, procs) deployments to avoid errors due to inter-dependencies?

Tags: sql-server

I have a fairly large amount of sql server objects that I would like to batch deploy.  Each object (table, view, procedure, etc) is in it's own file.

The problem is, many of the objects have interdependencies, so the order of creation is important, otherwise errors will occur.

Currently, I am deploying using a dos batch file that calls a controlling script into which I have manually specified the order of script execution, like so:

BATCH FILE:

```
SQLCMD -S %SERVER_NAME% -d %DATABASE_NAME% -i "DeployProcedures.sql"
```

SQL Script (DeployProcedures.sql):

```
:r view1.sql
:r view2.sql
:r view3.sql
etc
:r proc1.sql
:r proc2.sql
:r proc1.sql
etc
```

This works, but it is cumbersome to have to constantly keep this up to date.

Is there any other way of doing this?  I think I would even be happy with running the deploy 4 times, with suppressed or "do not fail" on errors for the first 3 iterations, and then only enable terminate on errors for the final iteration.

I would rather something self-authored rather than a commercial product like: http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/re-order-script-to-avoid-dependency-based-errors/

EDIT:  downvotes on a question regarding a problem *for which someone actually bothered to go through the trouble to write a commercial application* - sigh.

Comment: The only way I was able to figure out was to keep re-deploying all those that fail in a loop and stop that once there is a first round when none of the failed objects were successfully installed. Not really the most elegant solution... :D

Comment: That's an acceptable way to go about it in my opinion, but I don't know what the proper syntax is to ignore errors and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a "crude" but extremely straightforward way to handle it:

http://inedo.com/blog/using-source-control-to-manage-stored-procedures

Key excerpt:

> The rules of database objects in source control are simple: one file
>   per object (named after the object) that will DROP and then CREATE the
>   object. You can use a tool like Scriptio to extract existing objects
>   into files. Throw in a little file organization, and you're ready for
>   check-in:
>
> ```
>         1.FUNCTIONS\
>            1.FormatOrderNumber.sql
>         2.VIEWS\
>            1.OrdersWithTotals.sql
>            1.SalesReport.sql
>            2.OrdersPastDue.sql
>         3.PROCS\
>            1.AddItemToOrder.sql
>            1.ValidateOrder.sql
>            2.ProcessOrder.sql
> ```
>
> Note that the numeric prefixes ensure proper execution order.
>   Procedures can use Views, which in turn can use functions... but
>   usually not the other way around. And since a handful database objects
>   depend on other objects, those can prefixed with “2.” instead of “1.”.
>
> Execution of these scripts is just as easy, and can be accomplished
>   with a simple batch file:
>
> ```
>           FOR /R %%f IN (*.sql) DO (
>           ECHO Running %%f
>           OSQL -E -i "%%f" -n -b -d myDatabase -S myServer
>         )
> ```
>
> With scripts and a batch script set-up in source control, building
>   your database code is as easy as grabbing from source control and
>   clicking “execute scripts”.

Another possible approach is outlined here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/dependencies-and-references-in-sql-server/

(I'll paste in one script but there are others in that article worth checking out.)

```
Here is a routine that shows you the soft dependency order of the objects in your database, and lists the external dependencies of any objects. (note that a lot of entities in a database aren’t classed as objects. )


IF object_id (N'DependencyOrder') IS NOT NULL

    DROP FUNCTION dbo.DependencyOrder

GO



CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DependencyOrder()

/*  

summary:   >

 This table-valued function is designed to give you the order in which

 database objects should be created in order for a build to succeed

 without errors. It uses the sys.sql_expression_dependencies table

 for the information on this.

 it actually only gives the level 1,,n so within the level the order

 is irrelevant so could, i suppose be done in parallel!

 It works by putting in successive passes, on each pass adding in objects

 who, if they refer to objects, only refer to those already in the table

 or whose parent object is already in the table. It goes on until no more

 objects can be added or it has run out of breath. If it does more than

 ten iterations it gives up because there must be a circular reference  

 (I think that's impossible)



Revisions:

 - Author: Phil Factor

   Version: 1.0

   Modification: First cut

   date: 3rd Sept 2015

 example:

     - code: Select * from dbo.DependencyOrder() order by theorder desc

returns:   >

a table, giving the order in which database objects must be built



*/

RETURNS @DependencyOrder TABLE 

  (TheSchema VARCHAR(120) null, TheName VARCHAR(120) NOT null, Object_id INT PRIMARY KEY, TheOrder INT NOT null,iterations INT null,ExternalDependency VARCHAR(2000) null )

AS

-- body of the function

BEGIN

DECLARE @ii INT,@EndlessLoop INT,@Rowcount INT

SELECT @ii=1, @EndlessLoop=10, @RowCount=1

WHILE @rowcount>0 AND @endlessLoop>0

       BEGIN

       ;WITH candidates  (object_ID, Parent_object_id) AS

              (SELECT sys.objects.Object_ID,sys.objects.parent_Object_id

              FROM sys.objects

              LEFT OUTER JOIN @DependencyOrder Dep --not in the dependency table already

              ON dep.Object_id = objects.object_id

              WHERE dep.Object_id IS NULL

              AND type NOT IN ('s', 'sq','it')

              )

       INSERT INTO @DependencyOrder  (TheSchema,TheName,Object_id,TheOrder)

       SELECT  object_schema_name(c.Object_ID),object_name(c.Object_id),c.object_id, @ii

       FROM candidates c   INNER JOIN @DependencyOrder parent

       ON c.Parent_object_ID= parent.Object_ID

       UNION

       SELECT  object_schema_name(Object_ID),object_name(Object_id),object_id, @ii

        FROM candidates c 

       WHERE  Parent_object_id=0

       AND object_id NOT IN (

       SELECT c.object_id  

        FROM candidates c

               INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies

       ON object_ID=referencing_ID

       LEFT OUTER JOIN @DependencyOrder ReferedTo

       ON ReferedTo.object_id =referenced_ID

       WHERE ReferedTo.object_id IS NULL

       AND  referenced_id IS  NOT NULL--not a cross-database dependency

)

       SET @rowcount=@@rowcount

       SELECT @ii=@ii+1,@EndlessLoop=@EndlessLoop-1

       END 

       UPDATE  @dependencyOrder SET iterations= @ii-1

       UPDATE  @dependencyOrder  SET   ExternalDependency= ListOfDependencies

              FROM   

                 (SELECT Object_ID, STUFF(

                     (SELECT ', '+coalesce(referenced_server_name+'.','')

                     +coalesce(referenced_database_name+'.','')

                     +coalesce(referenced_schema_name+'.','')

                     +referenced_entity_name 

                     FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed

                     WHERE sed.referencing_ID=externalRefs.object_ID

                     and  referenced_database_name IS NOT NULL AND is_ambiguous=0

                     FOR Xml PATH (''), ROOT('i'), TYPE).value('/i[1]', 'varchar(max)')

                     ,1,2,'') ListOfDependencies

                 FROM @dependencyOrder externalRefs



                )f

              INNER JOIN @dependencyOrder d ON f.object_id=d.Object_ID



RETURN

END

GO
```

Answer (score 2):

sys.sql_expression_dependencies is your friend.

An example:

```
-- Show all the things that all objects depend on
SELECT o.name AS [Object], o.[type] AS [ObjectType], t.name AS [DependsOn], t.type AS [DependentObjectType]
  FROM sys.objects o
       INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies d ON o.object_id = d.referencing_id
       INNER JOIN sys.objects t ON d.referenced_id = t.object_id
 ORDER BY o.name, t.name
```

Basically, you can generate your file that runs the script in order based on the dependencies you find from this query.  It'll take some massaging for your application, but this should be a good start.  You can always add a filter to limit things to specific types, of course.  You can pretty much create all the tables in any order you want.  Views, Functions, and Stored Procedures (in that order) are a bit trickier... views especially can have recursive dependencies that can be difficult to deal with, but it's certainly possible (recursive CTEs can auto-generate order here as well).

Comment: Deriving the required order from sys.sql_expression_dependencies is the hard part I think.  And then once you've figured that out, it's probably a non-trivial exercise to come up with a full implementation of this.  I can't imagine I'm the first person to have encountered this issue, surely there must be some existing approaches out there.